# How to edit user privileges with JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

How can I edit user privileges of some MySQL servers with JetBrains DataGrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now right click a `database` or `schema` to navigate to "Tools" > "Modify Grants..".

[image: modify grants for a schema]

Answer (score 16):

As far as I can tell, the state of the art is that you either

- write+run hand-written SQL statements for user management (see MySQL docs at [1] )
- run DataGrip in the background while running MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin in the foreground and do the user management there

Let's hope that the situation improves, but right now there does not even seem to be a feature request for that.

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-account-management.html

Comment: There is now a feature request, but it has not seen a lot of activity: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3599